# call javascript validation function from view in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, validation

i want to validate a form in clint side in codeignigter. i have a view and a javascript function. how can i call the javascript function to validate the form. here is my code

```
    function validate()
    {
var txtSchoolName=document.getElementById('name');
var address=document.getElementById('address');
var contactNo1=document.getElementById('contactNo1');

    if((name.value==null)||(name.value=="")){
    alert("Enter School Name")
    name.focus()
    return false
    }
if((address.value==null)||(address.value=="")){
    alert("Provide Address")
    address.focus()
    return false
    }
if((contactNo1.value==null)||(contactNo1.value=="")){
    alert("Provide Contact Number")
    contactNo1.focus()
    return false
    }
   return true
  }
  </script>
  echo form_open_multipart('register_school/updateSchool');
    echo '<p>';

    echo '</br>';
    echo form_label('School Name : ','username',$attributes);
    echo form_input('name');

    echo form_label('School Address : ','username',$attributes);
    echo form_input('address');

    echo form_label('Contact No 1 : ','username',$attributes);
    echo form_input('contactNo');
            echo form_submit('submit', 'Save','validate()');        
    echo form_close();
```

Comment: Might sound a silly question but, do you want to validate it on submit?

Comment: I see you are already using the validate() function on form_submit, but, don't have to use it like 'onSubmit="validate()"' ?

Comment: yes i want a validate on submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive the right usage for `form_submit` third parameter is the same as for form_checkbox:

from the CI docs:

```
$js = 'onClick="some_function()"';

echo form_checkbox('newsletter', 'accept', TRUE, $js)
```

so your code should be

```
echo form_submit('submit', 'Save', 'onClick="validate()"');
```

or

```
 echo form_open_multipart('register_school/updateSchool', 'onSubmit="validate()"');
```

Comment: I edited my answer. Try it again please. The onSubmit event is only for the form. For the submit button it's the onClick event

Comment: i don't have 15 reputation so i could not mark it as answer. sorry for that. but thank you for your help.